# SSJS date time retrieval error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to retrieve the date-time in SSJS. I have created the below code on the cloud page, to retrieve the locale date time.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    try {
        var request = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now());
        Write(Stringify(request));

    } catch(err) {
        Write(Stringify(err));
    }
</script>
```

When I run this code in cloudpage, getting the below error:

> {"message":"Object expected:
> SystemDateToLocalDate","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException:
> Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at
> Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at
> Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
> Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at
> Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
> Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement
> statement)\r\n at
> Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor
> visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement
> statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor
> visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement
> statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected:
> SystemDateToLocalDate\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException'
> was thrown. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}

The below code works fine but the output is the systemdate. I want it to be the local time

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    try {
        /*var request = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now());
    
        Write(Stringify(request));*/
        
      var date= Now();

     var d = new Date(date); 

   Write(d);

    } 
    catch(err) {
        Write(Stringify(err));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the script working. Below script is generating the output as localdate time. I got the reference from [link](https://ampscript.xyz/tips-and-tricks/best-tips-and-tricks-in-ampscript-and-server-side-javascript/)

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    try {
    // Output the locatltime    
   var localTime = DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now());
   Write(localTime);
   //output the sytem time
   var systemTime = DateTime.LocalDateToSystemDate(Now());
   Write(systemTime);
    } 
    catch(err) {
        Write(Stringify(err));
    }
</script>
```